# Mininet+ GNS3: pingall fails + dhcp doesn't work

Tags: networking, dhcp, mininet

I'm still a beginner, I'm facing some issues and I need your help.

## 1

I integrated mininet to gns3 successfully, the mininet VM can ping all the routers and other VMs, Also it can get an address through dhcp immediately without problems. However, when I run this command,

```
sudo mn --controller=remote,ip=192.168.1.10, port=6653
```

the ovswitch connects to the floodlight controller but pingall fails.

## 2

I tried to add my network interface (eth0) to the my bridge (s1) in order to connect the mininet host to the internet, the dhclient takes long time and can't assign an IP address to the bridge.

- add eth0: `ovs-vsctl add-port s1 eth0`
- remove eth0's IP addressing: `ifconfig eth0 0`
- make s1 interface get a DHCP IP: `dhclient s1`

Im using:
floodlight master
ovs_version 2.5.4

GNS3 version 2.1.8 on Windows (64-bit) with Python 3.6.5 Qt 5.8.0 and PyQt 5.8.
ubuntu 16.04.4

Please can someone help me to solve these issues.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might get a better response to this on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/)

Comment: ok ... Thank you